# Lidando com objetos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para cada cartão cadastrado, eu redireciono o usuário para a página de visualização de cartões dele e ali listo todos os cartões que ele já cadastrou.

Cada cartão tem seu `nome`, então para cada cartão eu crio o `layout` e insiro o `nome`. Até aí tudo bem.

**Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:**

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT empresa FROM cartoes', [], function(tx, results){
                for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
                    var nomes = results.rows.item(i);

                    cartoesCadastrados(); //essa função cria o layout

                    console.log(Object.values(nomes));

                    $('.row').find('span').text(Object.values(nomes));
                }
```

Esse `console.log(Object.values(nomes));` me retorna os nomes dos cartões já cadastrados:

```
["Ebcard"]
["Claro"]
["Itaú"]
```

**Aqui é onde mora o problema:**

```
$('.row').find('span').text(Object.values(nomes));
```

Minha intenção nesse código acima é que para cada `layout` criado, inserisse o seu respectivo `nome`. O problema é que ele insere o mesmo nome para todos, o último que foi cadastrado, nesse caso, os **3 cartões cadastrados estão** com o `nome` de `Itaú`.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

**O layout de visualização do cartão cadastrado está assim:**

```
<html>
    <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- onde vai plotar o template -->
                    <div id="container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <template>
                <div class="row" id="corpo-cartoes">
                    <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 100%;">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="img/apresentacao.jpg">
                                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
                                <a href="#" ><i class="material-icons">code</i></a>

                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template> 
</html>

<script>
    function cartoesCadastrados() {
        var content = document.querySelector('template').content;
        document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(
        document.importNode(content, true));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Creio que se `Object.values(nomes)` te retorna um array, então você precisaria fazer `Object.values(nomes)[i]` para pegar cada um dos valores da array, não?

Comment: Já tentei e não funciona. Assim ele preenche só o primeiro.

Comment: O estranho é que se eu coloco console.log(Object.values(nomes)[i]); ele me retorna só o primeiro nome cadastrado, e o resto vem como undefined.

Comment: `$('.row').find('span').text(Object.values(nomes[i]));` não funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema é que você não está indexando as linhas do seu html, então a cada iteração o seu código jQuery atualiza a linha atual e também as linhas de todas as iterações anteriores com o mesmo valor.

Criei um trecho semelhante ao seu, com uma opção de solução.
Espero que seja útil.

```js
function cartoesCadastrados(idx) {
    var clone = document.importNode(document.querySelector('template').content, true);

    clone.querySelector("#corpo-cartoes")
      .classList.add(idx);

    document.querySelector('#container')
      .appendChild(clone);
}

var results = {
  rows: [ "Bradesco", "Itaú", "Banco do Brasil", "Caixa" ]
}

for (var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    var nomes = results.rows[i];       

    var idx = "item" + (i + 1);

    cartoesCadastrados(idx); //essa função cria o layout 

    $("." + idx).find('span').text(nomes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <!-- onde vai plotar o template -->
      <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<template>
    <div class="row" id="corpo-cartoes">
        <div class="col s12 m7" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="img/apresentacao.jpg">
                    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action icone-meu-cartao">
                    <a href="#" ><i class="material-icons">code</i></a>

                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">crop_free</i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons btn-editar">edit</i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: @Tfm consegue postar o console do erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Ele não da erro nenhum, só não preenche nada.

Comment: Talvez seja a maneira que estou adicionando meu layout para cada cartão cadastrado.. Vou editar a pergunta e mostrar ali em cima.

Comment: @Tfm Atualizei o exemplo conforme o seu código

Comment: Bah, não sei nem como te agradecer. Depois de uma tarde quebrando a cabeça com isso, nada melhor do que ver funcionando kkkk. Muito obrigada!!!

Comment: Hehe, sempre bom poder ajudar. Só um detalhe, editei o exemplo novamente, mais especificamente a função **cartoesCadastrados**, para corrigir um bug e tornar a seleção mais confiável, pegando a row por id ao invés de pegar pelo children.

Answer (score 0):

Isso você pode fazer de varias maneiras, uma alternativa seria assim.

```js
const array = ['itau', 'bradesco', 'santander', 'banco do brasil']


array.map(banco => {
  let querySelector = document.getElementById('list')
  
  querySelector.innerHTML += `<li>${banco}</li>`
})
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem.